# Change content of multiple files with `for-loop or other methods?

Tags: for-loop, sed

For files **file1**, **file2**, **file3**, Each of them have the same value in the **i**th line,like this

```
...
10  (the i th line)
...
```

How to change "10" in the **i** th line to another value, eg, 100, for all the files?

Comment: @Avinash Raj  I think it can be a command like `for i in \`seq 1 1 3\`; do sed 's/10/100' file$i >$i; done` It does not work.  Besides, I know this command I tried has not mentioned the line number  **i**.

Comment: you mean this `for i in *.*; do sed "10s/10/100/" "$i"; done`

Answer (score 0):

Don't need a for loop: use globbing to match all the files, and `sed -i` to edit them in-place

```
sed -i "$i{s/.*/100/}" file*
```